# c multithreading conflicts

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm trying to use multithreading to allow two tasks to run in parallel within one DLL, but my application keeps crashing, apparently due to some bad resource conflict management; here are the details:
I need to call the same function(DoGATrainAndRun) from a certain point along the main logic flow, passing a different value for one of the parameters, let the two run, then go back to the main logic flow, and use the two (different) sets of values returned from the 2 calls.

(this is in the main header file):

```
typedef struct 
{
  int PredictorId;
  int OutputType; 
  int Delta; 
  int Scale; 
  int Debug; 
  FILE* LogFile; 
  int TotalBars; 
  double CBaseVal; 
  double* HVal; 
  int PredictionLen; 
  double*** Forecast;
} t;
```

> 

(This is in the main logic flow):

```
hRunMutex=CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
arg->OutputType=FH; 
handle= (HANDLE) _beginthread( DoGATrainAndRun, 32768, (void*) arg);

arg->OutputType=FL; 
handle= (HANDLE) _beginthread( DoGATrainAndRun, 32768, (void*) arg);

do {} while (hRunMutex!=0);

CloseHandle(hRunMutex);
```

(this is at the end of DoGaTrainAndRun):

```
free(args);
ReleaseMutex( hRunMutex );
```

I'm pretty new to multi-threading, and I can't seem to figure this one out...

Comment: It looks like you are passing the same `arg` both threads.  That is probably wrong.

Comment: why do you say that? As you can see, I set arg->OutputType right before calling _beginthread

Comment: Can you please post the whole thread proc code with the places where you grab/release the mutex?

Comment: The same `arg` variable is passed to both threads.  You should create a different instance of the struct for each thread.

Comment: Does this work if you call `DoGATrainAndRun` twice serially?  Have you verified that `DoGATrainAndRun` is thread safe?

Comment: if you use two instances of the 't' struct, passing a different instance to each of the two threads, then combine them into a single instance of a 't' struct, the mutex items can be eliminated.

Comment: Since both threads are using the same common argument info (which no argument needs to be actually passed to the threads, because they use a common data area.) then main should only create the mutex, then each thread, when it wants to read/set the outputtype field in the 't' struct needs to first lock the mutex, then modify/read the variable, then unlock the mutex.  using a mutex means no one else can modify/read the variable until the mutex is unlocked.  This sequence of mutex_lock, handle variable, mutex_unlock must be performed every time the variable is referenced in the thread

Comment: Thanks @dohashi, DOGATrainandRun works fine when I call it serially (i.e. first with t->OutputType=FH , then with t->OutputType=FL). I'm not sure what "verify that DoGATrainAndRun is thread-safe" means; could you elaborate?

Comment: A function is thread safe if it can be called in parallel without the parallel executions interfering with each other.  An example of non-thread safe behaviour would be a function that accesses global data.  If one thread modifies that shared data while another thread is trying to read it, the second thread may get invalid values.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: @dohashi, I think you just described my problem: The function I'm calling uses an std::vector array variable defined in the global DLL space (i.e., all the functions in the DLL can access it). I wonder, would it help if I added an extra dimension to the array to be used to differentiate between the calls?

Comment: If you have the ability to modify the DLL, it would probably be best to just move the vector from the global memory space to a thread local one.  For example, you could move the vector into your struct `t` and then make sure that each thread gets is own copy of it when called.  You'll then have to pass the `t`, or a reference to the vector in t to each function that needs it.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the DLL, so I can modify it; the problem I see is, the vector in question is passed back and forth across nearly all of the functions in the DLL, for the various processing phases. Actually, the architecture is slightly more complicated, in that DOGATrainAndRun() just calls two other functions, DoGATraining() and DoGARun(), both contained in a different DLL. However, the problem remains

Comment: Oh, and I wrote that extra DLL, too.

Comment: Having to make this type of change is the consequence of choosing to use a global variable.  Globals often cause problems when used in parallel.  My opinion is you should avoid globals as much as possible.  Create a state struct and pass an instance around to the functions that need to access it.  You could also use Thread Local Storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms686991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @dohashi for your input. I'll have to redesign my DLLs.

Comment: Done. It works! I moved the global variable(s) to the local function called by DOGATraining, and passed them back/forth through all the other sub-functions. Thanks again, @dohashi

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things:

First, you're passing the same structure into both threads but just changing the `OutputType` value. If possible that the first thread will see `FL` and never see the value `FH`. The reason for this is how threads are scheduled. It's valid for your first thread to start and then be suspended. Then, your main thread creates the second thread, having set `OutputType` to `FL`. This thread starts and the first one is resumed as well. However, the first one now sees `OutputType` as `FL`.

Next, both threads are using the same structure, but one of them is freeing the memory. If the other thread is still using it after the other releases then you'll get undefined behaviour in the thread that is still using it. This will probably result in a crash.

You're attempt to wait for the threads to exit is wrong. You don't need the mutex and you certainly don't need to be spinning of it testing for zero. Just use [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HANDLE handles[2];

handles[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(...);
handles[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(...);

WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

This will stop your main thread from spinning around wasting cpu cycles. When the wait returns you'll know both threads have finished.

Putting this all together should give you something like this:

```
HANDLE handles[2];

t *arg1=malloc(sizeof(t));
arg1->OutputType=FH    
handles[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(DoGATrainAndRun, 32768, (void*)arg1);

t *arg2=malloc(sizeof(t));
arg2->OutputType=FL    
handles[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(DoGATrainAndRun, 32768, (void*)arg2);

WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
free(arg1);
free(arg2)
```

And don't release any memory in `DoGATrainAndRun`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed input; however, I must still be missing something, because the behavior is not changing; What I now have is the following:  `HANDLE handle[2];
 int ThreadId;
 t* arg[2]; `

Comment: `hRunMutex=CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
     for (i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++){
      arg[i]=(t*)malloc(2*sizeof(t));
      arg[i]->PredictorId=pr_id; arg[i]->Delta=vDelta; arg[i]->Scale=vHpScale; arg[i]->Debug=pDebug; arg[i]->LogFile=pLogFile; arg[i]->TotalBars=pTotalBars; arg[i]->CBaseVal=CBaseVal; arg[i]->HVal=vHVal[vPredictorType]; arg[i]->PredictionLen=pPredictionLen; arg[i]->Forecast=oForecast;
      arg[i]->OutputType=i; handle[i]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) DoGATrainAndRun, (void*) arg[i], 0, &ThreadId);
     }`

Comment: `WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, handle, TRUE, INFINITE);
     for (i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++) CloseHandle(handle[i]);`

Comment: @gcaglion - I've added another example

Comment: No luck; It now crashes when it calls WaitForMultipleObjects ; by looking at the stack , I can see the crash occours within the push_back method of some array variables

Comment: I removed all the thread-related calls from DoGATrainAndRun (mainly the free(), and replaced the block from the main flow with the one I'm posting below. Still no luck... Now it crashes on the call to WaitForMultipleObjects, and stack trace looks the same as before, where the crash occours when inizializing an array. What am I missing? Might this have something to do that I'm using std:vector variables in my main program?

Comment: for (i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++){
      arg[i]=(t*)malloc(2*sizeof(t));
      arg[i]->PredictorId=pr_id; arg[i]->Delta=vDelta; arg[i]->Scale=vHpScale; arg[i]->Debug=pDebug; arg[i]->LogFile=pLogFile; arg[i]->TotalBars=pTotalBars; arg[i]->CBaseVal=CBaseVal; arg[i]->HVal=vHVal[vPredictorType]; arg[i]->PredictionLen=pPredictionLen; arg[i]->Forecast=oForecast;
      arg[i]->OutputType=i; 
      handle[i]= (HANDLE)_beginthread(DoGATrainAndRun, 32768, (void*)arg[i]);
     }
     WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, handle, TRUE, INFINITE);
     for (i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++) free(arg[i]);